# Constructing lots of similar objects efficiently in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a python library which generates interactive visualisations using Bokeh. I find myself constructing a large number of widgets and was wondering about a more efficient way to structure my code. Consider the following minimal example (I am writing in an object orientated fashion and this is one of my class methods):

```
from bokeh.models.widgets.buttons import Button
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider

# ...
def _generate_widgets(self):
    """
    Generates the widget instances used for user interaction.
    """
    self.widget_names = ['start', 'change', 'do_something']
    self.widget_types = {'start':Button,
                         'change':Slider,
                         'do_something':Button}
    self.widget_args = {'start':{'label':'Start!',
                                 'width':200}},
                        'change':{'title':'Change value:',
                                  'width':200,
                                  'value':500,
                                  'start':0,
                                  'end':1000,
                                  'step':50},
                         'do_something':{'label':'Do Something!'}}
     self.widget_callbacks = {'start':self._start_callback,
                              'change':None,
                              'do_something':self_do_callback}

   # make the widgets
   self.widgets = {}
   for widget_name in self.widget_names:
        widget = self.widget_types[widget_name](**self.widget_args[widget_name])
        self.widgets[widget_name] = widget
```

I then assign the callbacks later. In this small example its not too bad, but when I have a high number of widgets (say 5+) the dictionary storing the properties of the widgets get quite large and I'm repeating a lot of code (the widget names). One advantage of this method is it allows me to add/remove widgets easily and not worry about the order within the dictionary. However I wonder if there is a more efficient way to write this?

For example, one idea I had was to make a button constructor and store the information in a list.

**TLDR:** How do people normally deal with hardcoding a large number of parameters to make similar objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having three attributes to store the information about the widgets, you could use a list of tuples with this information as such:

```
widget_definitions = [
    ('start', Button, { <start button kwargs> }, self._start_callback),
    ('change', Slider, { <change slider kwargs> }, None),
    ('do_something', Button, { <do something kwargs>, self._do_something)
]
```

Alternatively, you could have a single dictionary from the widget name to the other attributes.

```
widget_definitions = {
    'start': (Button, { <start button kwargs> }, self._start_callback),
    'change': (Slider, { <change slider kwargs> }, None),
    'do_something': (Button, { <do something kwargs> }, self._do_something)
}
```

The primary benefit is not runtime efficiency here but the fact that each widget definition is self-contained.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like this, it is nice having the widget definitions self-contained. 

I will wait for some more input to see if anyone has anything else to add to the conversation but think this could make my code more readable.


**EDIT**: misread your second comment.

Comment: I don't fully understand your needs but the single dictionary solution shown here may accomplish what you're looking for.